# Add key value pair to existing array or merge them

Tags: php, arrays

I have to arrays:

```
$tickets = $db->loadObjectList();
$tickets_info = $details['ticket_info'];
```

$tickets:

```
array (size=2)

0 => 
object(stdClass)[2924]
  public 'price' => string '100.000' 
  public 'name' => string 'Standard ticket'
1 => 
object(stdClass)[2972]
  public 'price' => string '150.000' 
  public 'name' => string 'Luxus ticket'
```

$tickets_info:

```
array (size=2)
0 => string '98'
1 => string '50'
```

I'm trying to add the 98 and 50 as 'available_tickets' to $tickets array like this:

```
0 =>
object(stdClass)[2924]
  public 'price' => string '100.000'
  public 'name' => string 'Standard ticket'
  public 'available_tickets' => string '98'
1 =>
object(stdClass)[2972]
  public 'price' => string '150.000'
  public 'name' => string 'Luxus ticket'
  public 'available_tickets' => string '50'
```

I have tried array_merge() and loop through, but nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: No, it will not work a way you are trying to do. because you have an object and you are trying to add new element in form of array.

Add new element in form of object only, like in given example below:

    $a = new stdClass();
    $a->test1 = 'test1';
    $a->test2 = 'test2';
    var_dump($a);

    $a->test3 = 'test3';
    var_dump($a);

Comment: try adding new property to the objects not as a new element to the array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with the following solution:

```
foreach ( $tickets as $key => $ticket ) {
  if( array_key_exists( $key, $tickets_info ) ) {
    $tickets[$key]->available_tickets = $tickets_info[$key];
  } else {
    trigger_error('There is no equivalence to ticket #' . $key);
  }
}
```

Comment: Working perfect!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$tickets = array( 0 =>array('price' =>  '100.000','name' => 'Standard ticket'),1 =>array( 'price' => '150.000','name' =>'Luxus ticket'));
$available = array(0=>98,1=>50);

foreach($tickets as $key =>$val)
{
    $tickets[$key]['available_tickets'] = $available[$key];
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($tickets);
?>
```

This will give you :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price] => 100.000
            [name] => Standard ticket
            [available_tickets] => 98
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price] => 150.000
            [name] => Luxus ticket
            [available_tickets] => 50
        )
```

)

**[LIVE DEMO](https://eval.in/574201)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use  array map to do that:

```
$tickets = array_map(function($a, $b) { $a->available_tickets = $b; return $a; }, $tickets, $tickets_info);
```

This will give you

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [price] => "100.000"
        [name] => "Standard ticket"
        [tickets_available] => "98"
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [price] => "150.000"
        [name] => "Deluxe ticket"
        [tickets_available] => "50"
    )

)
```